# How to repair Ubuntu GRUB bootloader from within Windows WITHOUT a live CD

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, grubrescue, boot-repair

I've been running Ubuntu 15.04 and wanted to install Windows 7 for dual boot, and it of course deleted the GRUB bootloader upon install. However, every time I try to use a live CD or USB to repair GRUB, it either stalls at the Ubuntu loading screen or goes directly to GRUB rescue. As such, I am unable to repair GRUB with a live CD or USB because I can't even get them to open properly.

I need a way to repair the bootloader from within Windows. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?